# MySQL command to change all occurrences of user user@* to use mysql_native_password

Tags: mysql

I have user@localhost, user@127.0.0.1, user@x.x.x.x about 15 times in the mysql user table.  I need to update all occurrences of this user at whatever host to use mysql_native_password - to essentially disable the use of unix sockets, so I can login remotely to localhost.

Would the command be something akin to:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'*'  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password'?
```

Will @'*' work?

Thanks

Comment: Update plugin to mysql_native_password and use wildcard `%` on where-clause to affect all users you want.

Comment: ALTER USER 'user'@'%'  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password'  even ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password' - both produced an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run:
`UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'user@%';`

Then run:
`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User = 'user@%';`

After that you can login with user with password "new_password".

Comment: as of mysql 5.7.x SET password = ... needs to read SET authentication_string = ...